# Print second last word from line in tab-delimited file

Tags: awk

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
SRR12519477.10276   164546  root    Bacteria    n   n   n   Proteobacteria  n   n   Betaproteobacteria  n   n   Burkholderiales n   n   Burkholderiaceae    n   n   n   Cupriavidus n   Cupriavidus taiwanensis n   
SRR12519477.41495   164546  root    Bacteria    n   n   n   Proteobacteria  n   n   Betaproteobacteria  n   n   Burkholderiales n   n   Burkholderiaceae    n   n   n   Cupriavidus n   Cupriavidus taiwanensis n   
SRR12519477.60308   60035   root    Bacteria    n   n   n   Proteobacteria  delta/epsilon subdivisions  n   Deltaproteobacteria n   n   Desulfuromonadales  n   n   Geobacteraceae  n   n   n   Geobacter   n   Geobacter bremensis     n   
SRR12519477.67099   1621989 root    Bacteria    n   n   n   Proteobacteria  delta/epsilon subdivisions  n   Deltaproteobacteria n   n   n   n   n   Candidatus Desulfofervidaceae   n   n   n   Candidatus Desulfofervidus  n   Candidatus Desulfofervidus auxilii     n
```

I would only like to know the last name before the last 'n' in one line, so the desired output is this:

```
Cupriavidus taiwanensis
Cupriavidus taiwanensis
Geobacter bremensis
Candidatus Desulfofervidus auxilii
```

However, I don't know how to do this. Also, one thing to note for this dataset, is that the words in one line are separated by tabs and not spaces however stack overflow does not let me add tabs. Therefore, I used several spaces on the places that contain tabs instead of spaces which is after the name: 'Candidatus Desulfofervidus auxilii' and 'Geobacter bremensis'. I think I have to use a variation of:

```
awk 'END {print $(NF-1), $NF}' file
```

However, this outputs:

```
n n
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I was going to say that if the awk script in your question outputs `n n` then your awk tool is broken but technically I can't say that as the value of `$<anything>` in the END section is undefined behavior per POSIX so any awk can do anything it likes with `$NF` or `$<anything-else>` and still be POSIX compliant. I strongly suspect your script doesn't REALLY output `n n` though as that'd be an odd choice by the providers vs printing the values from the last line read or printing null strings (the 2 alternatives we typically see).

Comment: It';s not the answer to your question but FYI a portable way to write the script in your question would be `awk '{lastVals=$(NF-1) OFS $NF} END{print lastVals}' file`

Answer (score 3):

You could try following `awk` program. Simple explanation would be, you need to set field separator as TAB for all the lines of Input_file. Then to print 2nd last field you need to use `$(NF-1)`. Also looks like your shown samples are not tab delimited, but if your actual Input_file is tab delimited then this should work.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} {print $(NF-1)}' Input_file
```

***Issues in OP's efforts:*** Just mentioning issues with OP's efforts here for future readers. First thing first, OP has NOT set field separator as `\t` then code is printing in `END` block of `awk`, which will be executed at last(when `awk` program is done with reading the whole Input_file), so that's why its printing only last value IMHO. Also if your 2nd last field is space delimited you need not to mention `$NF` then you can make it work by mentioning `$(NF-1)` itself.

Comment: thanks, I just checked my dataset again and indeed sometimes the second to last names are separated by a space (like in the case of Cupriavidus taiwanensis) and sometimes they are separated by tabs (like in the case of Geobacter bremensis and Candidatus Desulfofervidus auxilii). Unfortunately, the solution does not work for me yet, possibly because of this reason. I think you have to add a piece of code that says the second to last name can be separated by a tab OR by a space?

Comment: @bartjoosten, if your actual file is different than shown samples then please edit your samples which are near to your file so that we can test our solutions on same, thank you.

Comment: stackoverflow does not allow me to use the tab key for some reason so I used several spaces as clarification and edited my text in the original question

Comment: @bartjoosten the best way to post a question related to tab-separated input is to post a question about comma or semi-colon (or any other non-regexp-metachar that doesn't appear in your input) separated input instead so we can see the separators in your question and don't have to modify your example when we copy/paste it to test with, and then you just change the FS from comma or semi-colon to tab to run the posted solution on your real data.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
SRR12519477.10276"\t"164546"\t"root"\t"Bacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Proteobacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Betaproteobacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Burkholderiales n"\t"n"\t"Burkholderiaceae"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Cupriavidus"\t"n"\t"Cupriavidus taiwanensis"\t"n
SRR12519477.41495"\t"164546"\t"root"\t"Bacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Proteobacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Betaproteobacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Burkholderiales n"\t"n"\t"Burkholderiaceae"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Cupriavidus"\t"n"\t"Cupriavidus taiwanensis"\t"n
SRR12519477.60308"\t"60035"\t"root"\t"Bacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Proteobacteria"\t"delta/epsilon subdivisions"\t"n"\t"Deltaproteobacteria n"\t"n"\t"Desulfuromonadales"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Geobacteraceae"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Geobacter"\t"n"\t"Geobacter bremensis"\t"n
SRR12519477.67099"\t"1621989"\t"root"\t"Bacteria"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Proteobacteria"\t"delta/epsilon subdivisions"\t"n"\t"Deltaproteobacteria n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Candidatus Desulfofervidaceae"\t"n"\t"n"\t"n"\t"Candidatus Desulfofervidus"\t"n"\t"Candidatus Desulfofervidus auxilii"\t"n
```

Where the `"\t"` are tabs, you can do:

Pure Bash:

```
rev file.txt | cut -d $'\t' -f 2 | rev
```

Or `awk`:

```
awk -F '\t' '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt
```

Or `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/.*\t(.*)\t.*/\1/' file.txt
```

Comment: thanks, I just checked my dataset again and found that sometimes the second to last names are separated by a space (like in the case of Cupriavidus taiwanensis) and sometimes they are separated by tabs (like in the case of Geobacter bremensis and Candidatus Desulfofervidus auxilii). Unfortunately, the solutions you offered do not work for me yet, possibly because of this reason. I think you have to add a piece of code that says the second to last name can be separated by a tab OR by a space?

Comment: If the delimiter is a `' '` how do you know what is the name and  what is the previous column? Is the delimiter perhaps a `\t` and 2 or more spaces? If it is a single space, that is just jumbled text...